# momentJS convert possibility day into Date() js format

Tags: javascript, date, object, momentjs

I am trying to convert a date in format momentjs into a date from javascript native new Date().

The problem is that if I have `moment(myDay).toDate();` it converts to the current date, and I want the date from myDay.

myDay looks like: `"YYYY-MM-DD" => 2017-11-24` and I would like to have it with the format: `Fri Nov 24 2017 20:17:11 GMT+0100 (Hora estándar romance)` but I get `Thu Nov 16 2017 etc...`

It is possible to convert it like that way?

Comment: `moment('2017-11-24').toDate()` is like `Fri Nov 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)`. Isn't that what you wanted? If you wanted the hours and minutes you would have to include those in `myDay` string to be able to format it with Moment.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or a fiddle showing your issue? I agree with ThisClark, `moment('2017-11-24').toDate()` will give your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Don't need moment:

```
let [yr, mn, day] = myDay.split('-').map(Number);
// note that JS months are 0-11 not 1-12
let datestr = new Date(yr, mn - 1, dy).toString();
console.log(datestr); // "Fri Nov 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)"
```

Comment: The conversion to Number is superfluous. ;-)

Comment: @RobG you are correct, but subtracting 1 from a string just *feels* wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this:

```
moment(myDay, "YYYY-MM-DD").toString();
```

**moment().toString()** Returns an english string in a similar format to JS Date's .toString().

```
moment().toString() // "Sat Apr 30 2016 16:59:46 GMT-0500"
```